# Downgrading all projects in solution to only use net451 references

Tags: c#, asp.net, xunit, asp.net-core-1.0, xunit2

I initially started a WebAPI project using the ASP.NET Core 1.0 template and was trying to do everything with dnx451 and dnxcore50 specified in all project.json files across the solution.

I recently gave up on using anything related to dnxcore due to them not bringing everything over that I need, but still want to use the new project template. I am assuming there is no problem with this decision until core1.0 is officially released.

**Here is what I had:**
ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web API Project : dnx451, dnxcore50
Data Library - Class Library Package : dnx451, dotnet5.4
Business Library - Class Library Package : dnx451, dotnet5.4
Xunit2 Test Project - Class Library Package : dnx451, dnxcore50

**Now here is what I want:**
ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web API Project : dnx451
Data Library - Class Library Package : net451
Business Library - Class Library Package : net451
Xunit2 Test Project - Class Library Package : dnx451

Should I still be using Class Library Packages because the only reason I was using them was due to dnx. Additionally, should I still be using the XUnit version for both dnx and 451? Lets say I just wanted to use the latest stable version. Now my tests don't show up in VS.

Is it alright to still be using the new Core 1.0 Web API preview template stucture, but without using anything dnx or (core1.0) related? Additionally is it alright to still use Class Library Packages, but only for net451. And finally, for Unit testing should I still be using the 2.1.0-rc1-build204 or the stable version?

Answer (score 0):

Build up your Project from the scratch with the templates from 4.5.x, don't try to mix it.

RC2 is out since 16.05.2016, maybe you give this release a try?

I would not use .Net Core RC1 or RC2 for any production projects yet.
I use it only for learning the new concepts!

(Sorry i can't use comments yet.)

Edit: Answer to the comment.
Yes indeed, if you look at the changes of RC2 you will see many differences.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/05/16/announcing-asp-net-core-rc2/

https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rc2.html

Personally i have upgraded to RC2 and i will look at the new stuff, to be prepared for the final release.

Comment: So what your saying is do not use any of the preview templates yet, especially if not using .Net Core. Please update your post to reply.